# Tkinter Radiobutton Virtual "Click" (event)

Tags: python, tkinter, events, virtual

I'm crazy searching for doing this for days and days...

I need to simulate a virtual click on a Tkinter RadioButton.

In other words. Just when my application starts I need some virtual click event on a radiobutton to force a code execution. I would need my radiobutton in a second option but like if an user had clicked on it.

I readed some stuff abou virtual events but not in Radiobuttons...

Can anyone help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: do you need the button to appear checked?

Comment: it would probably be best just to run the code, instead of running it through a virtual event.

Comment: Yes. I need that the radiobutton appears checked and I need run a "callback" function to execute code. In other words, like the method invoke but invoking the "command" parameter, like a normal button.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds to me like you want the `invoke()` method - it simulates clicking the button

```
button = tk.Radiobutton()
button.invoke()
```

Comment: This works better that mine

Comment: Ohhh... shi****.  Sorry guys. I was confused. It's clearly to use invoke method. Sorry...

Comment: No worries - glad it worked out

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't be easy to create a virtual event, but you could just run your function on code startup, and than do something like

```
button = tk.Radiobutton(text="button", command=<Your Command>)
button.select()
```

Comment: Thanks and sorry for your time